# Is there an algorithm for price calculation on a bucket with 2 prices?

Tags: algorithms, finance

Is there some sort of algorithm to calculate the amount of shares on a bucket with 2 prices?

Example: A bucket has 2 assets called A and B. Asset A costs 100 USD and Asset B costs 50 USD. If I buy the bucket, the amount of money I put in gets divided by 50% towards asset A and 50% towards asset b. Lets say I "invest" 100 USD, that means I get 0.5 of asset a and one asset b.

How can I calculate the amount of shares of bucket I should own, in a way that I can reverse the calculation again to get the amount of asset a and b that I should own?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "should own" mean?  The rule seems fixed.  If you put in $\$1000$ then  $\$500$ goes to $A$, so $5$ shares of $A$, and $\$500$ goes to $B$, so $10$ shares.  So.... What are you asking?

Comment: @lulu I don't mean a the total amount of shares. I am thinking of a bucket which would represent ownership in those both assets. And how the amount I own would be effected if the prices change.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You gave precise algebraic rules for how an investment is to be allocated between the two assets.  And the rules have nothing to do with the share price(s).  Of course, other rules are possible...but it's hard to see what it is you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry. I am trying to find a way to calculate the amount of shares I would get if I invest in this bucket, with the prices of asset a and b constantly changing. For example, the easiest approach would be that 1 share of the bucket equates to 1 share of asset a and 1 share of asset b. But if the prices were drastically different, like asset a would be 1 USD and asset b 50 USD, then the portfolio would be very much equally weighted. If I were to split the amount that is invested into the bucket 50/50, then I couldn't track how much someone is entitled to.

Comment: But, just follow your rules.  If I put $1000$ into the bucket, then $500$ goes to each asset. Thus, if the asset prices are $a,b$ (in dollars per share) I buy $\frac {500}a$ shares of $A$ and $\frac {500}b$ shares of $B$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, but would it be possible to calculate the amount of shares of the bucket I get if I put in 1000? In a way that lets me calculate how many shares of asset a and b correspond to that number

Comment: Your question is simply not clear.  What is a "share in the bucket"?  If one share of the bucket contains one share of each $A,B$ a share of the bucket would cost $a+b$ dollars, but this is not compatible with your rules.  Your rules declare that investment in the bucket is not allocated this way.

Comment: The problem with your question is that the rules keep shifting.  If you declare that one share of the bucket consists of one share of $A$ and one share of $B$, that means that any investment in the bucket gets you an equal number of shares of each asset.  But this is not what you described.  You described some sort of investment mechanism that gives you equal dollar exposure to each asset which is very different.  I think that if you describe your possible investments clearly and precisely, all the ambiguity will go away.